# Why putting a / and " within a subprocess won't work?

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to execute a dos command in python like "date /t".
i assign it on a = "date /t". Then do subprocess.check_output(a). then print(a).
Prior to this, i imported subprocess module.
but when i execute it, I am getting an error like below.
Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python notes\func-2.py", line 3, in <module>
    subprocess.check_output(a)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 212, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as the error you are getting.

Comment: Edit the exception into your question, don't put it in a comment.

Comment: Also, please show us why you think the quotes or slash are the culprits.  Most likely, you're using `subprocess` in a way where the whole string `a` is being interpreted as a *program* to run rather than a *command* to be executed by DOS.  But without an MVCE, we're left guessing.  Show us your code!

Answer (score 1):

`date` in windows is not a program, it is a shell command. So the process you have to start is the shell.

```
r = subprocess.check_output('date /t', shell=True)
print r
```

Comment: thanks! it works. how about this: reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" | find /i "auto"

Comment: @sunnyvalecalifornia you don't have to execute a external program and start a new shell process only to read the registry!! Python can read the registry directly by using the `winreg` module! Example: `import winreg; print(winreg.ConnectRegistry(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER).OpenKey('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings'))` See the docs in https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html or ask another question if you're stuck!

Comment: Thanks @nosklo. Here is my code:def AutoConfigURL():
    hKey = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings")
    result = _winreg.QueryValueEx(hKey, "AutoConfigURL")
    return result[0]